# Angular -> Can the text in an HTML Select be different than what the user selected from the drop down list?

Tags: html, angular, html-select, optgroup

I am working (in an Angular project) with a form where the user selects something from a HTML Select. from the example below, the "Cat" and "Dog" are optgroup(s) and the other things listed are option(s) attributes. Im wondering if it is possible to have the user select from the drop down, say the "Lion" option, and the text that populates the collapsed version of the drop down to read something like.. Cat: Lion.

Cat

- Lion
- Bobcat
  Dog
- Wolf
- Clifford

Is it possible to do this with just Angular (not jquery)

thanks!

---

EDIT:

thanks to the help of shashank sharma's comment i was able to figure it out. i used the example he gave and was able to get it to work by making the label a variable in the typescript and then setting that variable in the onCategorySelection function

thing.component.html

`<mat-label>{{animalKingdom}}</mat-label>`

thing.component.ts

```
onCategorySelection(event: MatOptionSelectionChange, groupName: string) {
    if (event.isUserInput) {
      this.selected = groupName +  ':' + event.source.viewValue;
     ----->>>> this.animalKingdom = groupName +  ':' + event.source.viewValue;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Very possible. You might want to look at the ngSelect package (https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select) - it supports custom templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution of this problem can't be done with `selectionChange` event, we have to use `onSelectionChange` event of MatOption which gives us info of `MatOptionGroup`.

For example:

```
<mat-select>
  <mat-optgroup *ngFor="let group of categoryGroups"
                [label]="group.name">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let category of group.options"
                [value]="category.value" (onSelectionChange)="onCategorySelection($event, group.name)">
       {{category.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-optgroup>

</mat-select>
```

and Typescript

```
onCategorySelection(event: MatOptionSelectionChange, groupName: string) {
    if (event.isUserInput) {
      this.groupName = groupName; 
    }
  }
```

I have create a working example for you [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3e6blt-lfiycd).

PS: remember onSelectionChanged() is fired not only when an option is selected but also when it is deselected so if you are using met select with checkbox where we select and deselct onSelectionChanged() will fire both time (can be handled with some checks).

Comment: thanks for the help, im going to try this out to see if i can get it to work! the functionality is a bit different than i need though. in your working example, after you select from the drop down, the box that you would be selecting from still reads "Animal Kingdom" and not the concatenation of the optiongroup and the option that were selected

Comment: Thanks for feedback @Conrad, i don't about that condition i have updated code in stackblitz link please see of it can full fill your requirements. please accept / upvote answer if it works for you